# How to make a transition animation in Aframe similar to Street View or Matterport?

Tags: reactjs, three.js, aframe

I'm using an aframe-react library in a project, and I need to make the transitions between scenes similar to Street View and Matterport (https://matterport.com/discover/space/PPJGbzBA9JA).

In these examples cited, the transition happens as if one image were superimposed on another, and the previous one was disappearing and the new one taking shape.

Here is my current code:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>

<script src="https://aframe.io/releases/1.0.0/aframe.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/aframe-animation-component@^4.1.2/dist/aframe-animation-component.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/aframe-look-at-component@0.5.1/dist/aframe-look-at-component.min.js"></script>

<script>
      AFRAME.registerComponent('infogroup',{
        init:function(){
            this.el.addEventListener('reloadinfo',function(evt){
            //alert(evt.detail.currinfo+"   "+evt.detail.newinfo);
            //get the entire current spot group and scale it to 0
            var currinfogroup=document.getElementById(evt.detail.currinfo);
            currinfogroup.setAttribute("scale","0 0 0");
            
            //get the entire new spot group and scale it to 1
            var newinfogroup=document.getElementById(evt.detail.newinfo);
            newinfogroup.setAttribute("scale","1 1 1");
          });
        }
      });
      AFRAME.registerComponent('infoicon',{
        schema:{
          linkto:{type:"string",default:""},
          infogroup:{type:"string",default:""}
        },
        init:function(){
          
          //add image source of hotspot icon
          this.el.setAttribute("src","#info-icon");
          //resize
          this.el.setAttribute("scale","0.5 0.5 0.5");
          //make the icon look at the camera all the time
          this.el.setAttribute("look-at","#cam");
          
          var data=this.data;
          
          this.el.addEventListener('click',function(){
            this.setAttribute("scale","2.5 1.25 1");
            this.setAttribute("src",data.infolink);
          });
          this.el.addEventListener('mouseleave',function(){
            this.setAttribute("scale","0.5 0.5 0.5");
            this.setAttribute("src","#info-icon");
            
            var cur=document.getElementById("cursor-visual");
            cur.emit("stopFuse");
          });
          this.el.addEventListener('mouseenter', function (evt) {
            var cur=document.getElementById("cursor-visual");
            cur.emit("startFuse");
            
          });
        }
      });
      
      
      AFRAME.registerComponent('hotspots',{
        init:function(){
            this.el.addEventListener('reloadspots',function(evt){
            
            //get the entire current spot group and scale it to 0
            var currspotgroup=document.getElementById(evt.detail.currspots);
            currspotgroup.setAttribute("scale","0 0 0");
            
            //get the entire new spot group and scale it to 1
            var newspotgroup=document.getElementById(evt.detail.newspots);
            newspotgroup.setAttribute("scale","1 1 1");
          });
        }
      });
      
      
      function loadNewSpotDetails()
      {
        
        //set the skybox source to the new image as per the spot
          var sky=document.getElementById("skybox");
          sky.setAttribute("src",ndata.linkto);
            
          var spotcomp=document.getElementById("spots");
          var currspots=nthis.parentElement.getAttribute("id");
          //create event for spots component to change the spots data
          spotcomp.emit('reloadspots',{newspots:ndata.spotgroup,currspots:currspots});


          var infocomp=document.getElementById("infos");
          var currinfo=ndata.infoparent;
          //create event for spots component to change the spots data
          infocomp.emit('reloadinfo',{currinfo:currinfo,newinfo:ndata.infogroup});  
          
          //var ncam=document.getElementById("cam");
          //this.setAttribute("camera","fov",80);
          this.emit("zoomout");
        
          var fp=document.getElementById("camfadeplane");
          fp.emit("camFadeOut");
        
      }
      var ndata;
      var nthis;
      
      
      AFRAME.registerComponent('spot',{
        schema:{
          linkto:{type:"string",default:""},
          spotgroup:{type:"string",default:""},
          infogroup:{type:"string",default:""},
          infoparent:{type:"string",default:""}
        },
        init:function(){
          
          //add image source of hotspot icon
          this.el.setAttribute("src","#hotspot");
          //make the icon look at the camera all the time
          this.el.setAttribute("look-at","#cam");
          
          var data=this.data;
          
          this.el.addEventListener('click',function(){
            ndata=data;
            nthis=this;
            
            var cam=document.getElementById("cam");
            cam.emit("zoomin");
            
            var fp=document.getElementById("camfadeplane");
            fp.emit("camFadeIn");
            //alert("Start zoom");
          });
          this.el.addEventListener('mouseleave',function(){
            var cur=document.getElementById("cursor-visual");
            cur.emit("stopFuse");
          });
          this.el.addEventListener('mouseenter', function (evt) {
            var cur=document.getElementById("cursor-visual");
            cur.emit("startFuse");
          });
        }
      });
      
      
    </script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <a-scene background="color: #FAFAFA" inspector="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/gh/aframevr/aframe-inspector@master/dist/aframe-inspector.min.js">
      <a-assets>
        <img id="room1" src="https://cdn.glitch.global/6fdae127-bb8b-4b78-ba20-187ded556d21/light.webp?v=1669832472416">
        <img id="room2" src="https://cdn.glitch.global/6fdae127-bb8b-4b78-ba20-187ded556d21/black.webp?v=1669832521205">
        <img id="room3" src="https://cdn.glitch.com/c52283d6-3489-44e4-b56b-43550d1bc76c%2F3.jpg?v=1564408737583">
        <img id="room4" src="https://cdn.glitch.com/c52283d6-3489-44e4-b56b-43550d1bc76c%2F4.jpg?v=1564408736299">
        
        <img id="info1" src="https://cdn.glitch.com/c52283d6-3489-44e4-b56b-43550d1bc76c%2Fpanel-1.png?v=1564467657593">
        <img id="info2" src="https://cdn.glitch.com/c52283d6-3489-44e4-b56b-43550d1bc76c%2Fpanel-2.png?v=1564467657745">
        <img id="info3" src="https://cdn.glitch.com/c52283d6-3489-44e4-b56b-43550d1bc76c%2Fpanel-3.png?v=1564469664126">
        <img id="info4" src="https://cdn.glitch.com/c52283d6-3489-44e4-b56b-43550d1bc76c%2Fpanel-4.png?v=1564470362318">
        
        <img id="hotspot" src="https://cdn.glitch.com/c52283d6-3489-44e4-b56b-43550d1bc76c%2Fhotspot.png?v=1564471993959">
        <img id="info-icon" src="https://cdn.glitch.com/c52283d6-3489-44e4-b56b-43550d1bc76c%2Finfo-icon.png?v=1564471994218">
      </a-assets>
      <!-- room teleport hotspots -->
      <a-entity id="spots" hotspots>
        <a-entity id="group-room1">
          <a-image spot="linkto:#room2;spotgroup:group-room2;infogroup:infogroup-room2;infoparent:infogroup-room1" position="-10 1.6 0"></a-image>
        </a-entity>
        <a-entity id="group-room2" scale="0 0 0">
          <a-image spot="linkto:#room1;spotgroup:group-room1;infogroup:infogroup-room1;infoparent:infogroup-room2" position="-8 1.60 0"></a-image>
        </a-entity>
        <a-entity id="group-room3" scale="0 0 0">
          <a-image spot="linkto:#room2;spotgroup:group-room2;infogroup:infogroup-room2;infoparent:infogroup-room3" position="10 0 4"></a-image>
        </a-entity>
        <a-entity id="group-room4" scale="0 0 0">
          <a-image spot="linkto:#room2;spotgroup:group-room2;infogroup:infogroup-room2;infoparent:infogroup-room4" position="0 0 10"></a-image>
        </a-entity>
      </a-entity>
      
      <!-- info spots -->
      <a-entity id="infos" infogroup>
        <a-entity id="infogroup-room1">
          <a-image infoicon="infolink:#info1" position="-3 1.6 -3"></a-image>
        </a-entity>
        <a-entity id="infogroup-room2" scale="0 0 0">
          <a-image infoicon="infolink:#info4" position="-3 1.6 -3"></a-image>
        </a-entity>
        <a-entity id="infogroup-room3" scale="0 0 0">
          <a-image infoicon="infolink:#info2" position="0 0 4"></a-image>
          <a-image infoicon="infolink:#info4" position="3 0 -2"></a-image>
        </a-entity>
        <a-entity id="infogroup-room4" scale="0 0 0">
          <a-image infoicon="infolink:#info3" position="5 0 0"></a-image>
        </a-entity>
      </a-entity>
      
      <a-entity id="cam" camera="fov:80" position="0 1.6 0" look-controls
                animation__zoomin="property:camera.fov;dur:2000;to:50;startEvents:zoomin;"
                animation__zoomout="property:camera.fov;dur:1000;to:80;startEvents:zoomout;">
        
        <a-entity id="cursor-visual" cursor="fuse:true;fuseTimeout:2000" 
                  material="shader:flat;color:#09B4FF" 
                  position="0 0 -1" 
                  geometry="primitive: ring; radiusInner: 0.01; radiusOuter: 0.015;thetaLength:0"
                  animation__mouseenter="property: geometry.thetaLength; dir: alternate; dur: 2000;
                                easing: easeInSine; from:0;to: 360;startEvents:startFuse;pauseEvents:stopFuse;autoplay:false"
                  
                  animation__mouseleave="property: geometry.thetaLength; dir: alternate; dur: 500;
                                easing: easeInSine; to: 0;startEvents:stopFuse;autoplay:false">
          <a-entity geometry="primitive:ring;radiusOuter:0.015;radiusInner:0.01" material="shader:flat;color:#000000"></a-entity>
        </a-entity>
        <a-plane id="camfadeplane" rotation="10 0.5 0" position="0 0 -0.5" material="color:#000000;transparent:true;opacity:0" width="2" height="2"
                 animation__fadein="property:material.opacity;to:1;dur:2000;startEvents:camFadeIn"
                 animation__fadeout="property:material.opacity;to:0;dur:200;startEvents:camFadeOut"></a-plane>
      </a-entity>
      <a-sky id="skybox" src="#room1"></a-sky>
    </a-scene>
    <script>
      var ccam=document.getElementById("cam");
      ccam.addEventListener("animationcomplete",loadNewSpotDetails);
    </script>

</html>
```

I would like a transition between images/scenes similar to the examples cited above (Google Street View and Matterport).

Does anyone have any ideas?

Comment: Please include the code directly in your post

Comment: And please make sure you state what you expect to happen so we can help you out